# Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/squareup/leakcanary/watcher/R

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, leakcanary

After adding LeakCanary as a dependency to my android gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.2'
```

I've got this error when building application:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/squareup/leakcanary/watcher/R;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

I'm not including this library anywhere else, and without this *compile* dependency of leakcanary, my application is building fine.

I tried to look if I have some hidden canary dependency

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile | grep com.squareup
 \--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.2
      \--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-analyzer:1.5.2
           +--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-watcher:1.5.2
           \--- com.squareup.haha:haha:2.0.3
```

but there is only this expected one (I assume).

Exactly the same output is when I'm including this library using code from their FAQ

```
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.2'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.2'
```

Comment: Have you added multidexEnabled true in build.gradle ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Also dexOptions:         _preDexLibraries = false_ and _additionalParameters = ['--core-library']_

Comment: Hm, this preDexLibraries was leftover from previous developer, I never checked if it is necessary. But when I commented this out, build passed!

Comment: Yes, you have to remove that !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is related to `dex` file (Android bytecode for your .class files)

`multidex` is needed when your code methods exceed the max limit on a single `dex` file which is 64k methods calls.

`preDexLibraries` is used when you want to build `dex` file out of libraries so that you don't build dex files of the library in further builds. In your case, because of this, it was creating 2 instances of the library dex files and causing error -

`already added: Lcom/squareup/leakcanary/watcher/R;","sources"`